# New Keycloak image with own changes crashes directly

Tags: docker, jboss, dockerfile, keycloak

I have a weird problem with Docker and hope someone here can help me :)

I want to create a keycloak image that is derived from the image jboss/keycloak. The idea is that in the Dockerfile also a preconfigured standalone.xml is copied into the image and keycloak can start directly without manual work.

But as soon as I write for example a

```
"CMD touch /opt/test.txt"
```

into the file the container crashes with the message "12:02:14,290 INFO [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.9.1.Final
WFLYSRV0073: Invalid option '/bin/sh'"

This is just a new file with no purpose, the changes to the .xml are not in there yet.

As soon as I put only the FROM back in and rebuild everything works again.

I thought through the layers in the container you could mod an image, but here it doesn't seem to work. Can someone tell me why ?

So far it has always worked with the alpine image, but I don't want to build the whole keycloak setup again myself, when there is already an official image for it.

This is basically what I had in mind:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:X.XX
CMD rm /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
COPY ./keycloak/standalone.xml /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
CMD rm
```

to

```
RUN rm
```

`RUN` is part of building. every RUN command is executed while your image is built.
With `CMD` you define (or override) the default command when running/starting a container based on your image (and you don't want to change keycloaks default CMD)